# Using window.print by passing some content as string

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can someone help me out with this one.
I have an MVC page where I have  a print button. When clicking on print I need to open a print popup dialog (the same one that we get when we hit Ctrl+P). But when clicking on print, I have a logic to get some content as string from code behind and pass it to the print window.

I tried to open a popup when clicking on print button and doing Print functionality by using window.print but this works only if we have the content to print along with the button.

Edit:

[image]

If you see the above picture, I have a button with some label "Hi click below button to print content". When I click on print button, I need to have some other content not in this page to be sent to the printer.

Comment: `window.print();` prints the contents of the current document. If you want to print _some content as string_ then you need to add it to the DOM. Its not clear what you trying to achieve.

Comment: FAIK, you cant. You could maybe handle the [window.onbeforeprint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeprint) event to load and display the content (and hide other content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have it in the browser for it to print. Your best shot is to AJAX the content into a content `div`. Then, set the rest of the DOM to `visibility: hidden`. In CSS, you can do media queries like `@media print { }` to apply certain styles only when you print.

If you can imagine, the printer doesn't know HTML / CSS. Only the browser does and you can tell it the media you wish to target.